# C/OpenGL - Unable to modify cubes independently?

Tags: c, opengl, rubiks-cube

This is my first time working properly with OpenGL, although I have worked a little bit with C before

I have written my own drawCube function which takes in an coordinates array for the origin of the cube.

I was hoping the code would draw the cubes all wonky in regards to one another but they're not. Nor does it draw the other two separate cubes. I've spent a few hours going over this but have no idea why. Is it because drawCube isn't returning something usable for display(), if so what does it need to return?

As you might be able to tell this will end up being a Rubik's Cube. I've got half an idea of what to do with the data structure once I've done this, but until then I feel stuck

```
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear screen

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    int x, y, z = 0;
    for (z = -1; z < 2; z++) {
        for (y = -1; y < 2; y++) {
            for (x = -1; x < 2; x++) {
                float origin[3] = {x, y, z};
                glPushMatrix();
                    glTranslatef(x, y, z);
                    glRotatef(45, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5);
                    drawCube(origin);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
        }
    }

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(1,1,0);
        glRotatef(45, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5);
        glColor3ub(255,0,255);
        float origin0[3] = {-10, 10, 0};
        drawCube(origin0);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(1,-1,0);
        glRotatef(45, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5);
        glColor3ub(255,0,0);
        float origin1[3] = {10, -10, 0};
        drawCube(origin1);
    glPopMatrix();

    // Double buffering effect
    //glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

And the drawCube function:

```
void drawCube(float origin[]) {
    // Rotates the cube
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Rotate when user changes rotate_x and rotate_y
    glRotatef(rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    //printf("X: %f Y: %f", rotate_x, rotate_y);

    // Use glTranslate(x,y,z) to move it
    //glTranslatef(0.1, 0.0, 0.0);

    glScalef(0.2,0.2,0.2);

    // Define the vertices counterclockwise. Not important now but will be once
    // start to work with lighting, textures etc

    // Red side - FRONT
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); // Start drawing front of cube
        glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(origin[0]-0.5, origin[1]-0.5, origin[2]-0.5); // Vertex 1
        glVertex3f(origin[0]-0.5, origin[1]+0.5, origin[2]-0.5); // Vertex 2
        glVertex3f(origin[0]+0.5, origin[1]+0.5, origin[2]-0.5); // Vertex 3
        glVertex3f(origin[0]+0.5, origin[1]-0.5, origin[2]-0.5); // Vertex 4
    glEnd();

    // Orange side - BACK
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(   1.0,  0.5, 0.0 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]+0.5, origin[1]-0.5, origin[2]+0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]+0.5, origin[1]+0.5, origin[2]+0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]-0.5, origin[1]+0.5, origin[2]+0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]-0.5, origin[1]-0.5, origin[2]+0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // White side - RIGHT
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(  1.0,  1.0,  1.0 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]+0.5, origin[1]-0.5, origin[2]-0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]+0.5, origin[1]+0.5, origin[2]-0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]+0.5, origin[1]+0.5, origin[2]+0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]+0.5, origin[1]-0.5, origin[2]+0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Yellow side - LEFT
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(   1.0,  1.0,  0.0 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]-0.5, origin[1]-0.5, origin[2]+0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]-0.5, origin[1]+0.5, origin[2]+0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]-0.5, origin[1]+0.5, origin[2]-0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]-0.5, origin[1]-0.5, origin[2]-0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Green side - TOP
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(   0.0,  1.0,  0.0 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]+0.5,  origin[1]+0.5, origin[2]+0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]+0.5,  origin[1]+0.5, origin[2]-0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]-0.5,  origin[1]+0.5, origin[2]-0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]-0.5,  origin[1]+0.5, origin[2]+0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Blue side - BOTTOM
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(   0.0,  0.0,  1.0 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]+0.5, origin[1]-0.5, origin[2]-0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]+0.5, origin[1]-0.5, origin[2]+0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]-0.5, origin[1]-0.5, origin[2]+0.5 );
        glVertex3f( origin[0]-0.5, origin[1]-0.5, origin[2]-0.5 );
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: You call glLoadIdentity in drawCube, this basically resets your matrix stack so it makes every call to drawCube draw the exact same cube: all previous matrix operations between the drawcalls are discarded by the glLoadIdentity call. Remove it and see what happens, it may either solve your problem or present a new one.

Comment: Thanks a lot Henk. That of course brings up a new problem. Say I rotate a slice 90 degrees just using if x == -1 in display(). It looks okay if looked at face on but goes wrong if you go off axis like so
http://imgur.com/JV9M42Q

Comment: Well I'm afraid I'm not a wizard with the old OpenGL functions so I'm not sure. I think in the picture the cube itself is fixed, but the camera is rotated around the cube? And the picture results from calling `glRotatef(45, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5);` which will rotate around vector(0,1,0.5). Because that sounds wrong to me, shouldn't you just be rotating around an axis perpendicular to the set of cubes you rotate, at the center of those cubes? Could you explain your sequence of rotations more, especially the rotate_x/y variables.

Answer (score -1):

It might be useful to look at some working Rubik's cube code in OpenGL.

Here is some code that takes the corners and draws them:

https://github.com/nathansttt/hog2/blob/master/environments/RubiksCubeCorners.cpp#L594

Note that it's drawing a black background and then the colors on top of that.

There is another class for drawing the edges that does it similarly.

Above that is a class that draws the whole cube by drawing the edges and corners separately.

On top of this is code that does the rotations when pieces move. Here is the main calling class for some code that interpolates between two Rubik cube states:

https://github.com/nathansttt/hog2/blob/master/environments/RubiksCube.cpp#L648

Not that overall this is not high performance code, and isn't the modern way to use OpenGL. But, it works, which is what is most important for this code.